# Espresso pressBack() to check if back navigation works with Jetpack Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm currently testing my navigation (Jetpack + Espresso). I have 2 fragments:

- Fragment 1 contains a RecyclerView
- Fragment 2 is used to add another entry to the RecyclerView

I've already written the test to navigate from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2:

```
    @Test
    fun clickAddItemButton_navigateToAddItemFragment() {
        val navController = mock(NavController::class.java)
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<ToDoListFragment> {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
        }
        onView(withId(R.id.fabAddItem)).perform(click())
        verify(navController).navigate(
            ToDoListFragmentDirections.actionToDoListFragmentToAddItemFragment()
        )
    }
```

How can I test the back navigation from Fragment2 to Fragment1? The test I have so far throws an exception:

```
@Test
fun pressBackButton_navigateToListFragment() {
    val navController = Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<AddItemFragment> {
        Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
    }

    // simulate back button press
    pressBack()

    // verify navigation to second fragment
    Mockito.verify(navController).navigate(
        AddItemFragmentDirections.actionAddItemFragmentToToDoListFragment()
    )
}
```

Exception:

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: Pressed back and killed the app
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:96)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:322)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:178)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:119)
at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack(Espresso.java:229)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you have implemented the correct back navigation handling in the app code. It looks like you're trying to navigate from fragment #2 to #1 via a navigation action, which is not normally how navigation works. Fragment #2 would simply be removed from the back stack when you press back.

Comment: I'm using the standard, out of the box Jetpack Back Navigation. I just set up the navigation using the nav graph, added the navController to my activity and also specifically handled the up button. Should I implement a custom back navigation where I pop the fragment from the backstack to be able to test it?

Comment: I've also written another version of the test above that checks if the fragment was removed from the backstack: `Mockito.verify(navController).popBackStack()` after setting the popUpTo property in my nav graph, but the test still fails with the same exception

Comment: Did you try to test it on an emulator. Especially with those navigation things I have problems on real devices.

Answer (score 1):

As per your failed test, you simply pressing back from **AddItemFragment** which is only fragment in your container. That is reason its failing. To make it properly work, first launch **ToDoListFragment** , navigate to AddItemFragment then pressback() to verify you moved to listfragment. Basically code in *clickAddItemButton_navigateToAddItemFragment* need to placed first in second test.